# Как повернуть изображение,текст,или элемент управления в WinForms?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, rotation

Нужно сделать "стрелку" ,которая будет поворачиваться на заданное пользователем  количество градусов. Как это будет реализовано неважно. Можно поворачивать label  с текстом "------>" или pictureBox с картинкой. Такое возможно реализовать? Обыскал уже весь интернет,нашел только способ поворачивать на 90,180,270 градусов.

Comment: [Graphics.RotateTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 2):

Неплохой пример кода (с большим количеством сопровождающих комментариев) для поворота картинки в WinForms:

```
/// <summary>
/// method to rotate an image either clockwise or counter-clockwise
/// </summary>
/// <param name="img">the image to be rotated</param>
/// <param name="rotationAngle">the angle (in degrees).
/// NOTE: 
/// Positive values will rotate clockwise negative values will rotate counter-clockwise
/// </param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static Image RotateImage(Image img, float rotationAngle)
{
    //create an empty Bitmap image
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height);

    //turn the Bitmap into a Graphics object
    Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

    //now we set the rotation point to the center of our image
    gfx.TranslateTransform((float)bmp.Width / 2, (float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //now rotate the image
    gfx.RotateTransform(rotationAngle);
    gfx.TranslateTransform(-(float)bmp.Width / 2, -(float)bmp.Height / 2);

    //set the InterpolationMode to HighQualityBicubic so to ensure a high
    //quality image once it is transformed to the specified size
    gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

    //now draw our new image onto the graphics object
    gfx.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));

    //dispose of our Graphics object
    gfx.Dispose();

    return bmp; //return the image
}
```

Где `rotationAngle` - это угол поворота. Полезная ссылка: [Graphics.RotateTransform](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.rotatetransform?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Ссылка на источник: [How do I rotate a picture in WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2163854/5275890)

Comment: А если написать на WPF - так там у Control'а просто есть параметр - "угол поворота".